# Elasticsearch not returns all fields for each hit row

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I have a problem with my Elasticsearch index. I'm trying to get some fields for each row, but elastic returns not all of them when I'm searching. If I try to 'get' document by id - it returns all fields

In my query I'm trying to use _source field, but it not works - query returns only several fields from _source.

Is there any restrictions on it? Restrictions on amount or size of _source fields?

Elastic version 7.1

My mapping:

```
    "video": {
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 128
                },
                "basic_edge_ngram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "basic_edge_ngram_analyzer"
                },
                "basic_edge_ngram_analyzer_no_digit": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "basic_edge_ngram_analyzer_no_digit"
                },
                "basic_ngram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "basic_ngram_analyzer"
                },
                "basic_ngram_analyzer_no_digit": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "basic_ngram_analyzer_no_digit"
                },
                "numeric_analyzer": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "numeric_analyzer"
                },
                "translit_analyzer": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "translit_analyzer"
                },
                "translit_double_metaphone_analyzer": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "translit_double_metaphone_analyzer"
                }
            }
        },
        "inverse_title": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 128
                },
                "basic_edge_ngram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "basic_edge_ngram_analyzer"
                },
                "basic_edge_ngram_analyzer_no_digit": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "basic_edge_ngram_analyzer_no_digit"
                },
                "basic_ngram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "basic_ngram_analyzer"
                },
                "basic_ngram_analyzer_no_digit": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "basic_ngram_analyzer_no_digit"
                },
                "numeric_analyzer": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "numeric_analyzer"
                },
                "translit_analyzer": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "translit_analyzer"
                },
                "translit_double_metaphone_analyzer": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "translit_double_metaphone_analyzer"
                }
            }
        },
        "thumbnail_url": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "store": "true"
        },
        "is_classic": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "store": "true"
        },
        "is_club": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "store": "true"
        },
        "product_id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "store": "true"
        },
        "duration": {
            "type": "integer",
            "store": "true"
        },
        "feed_name": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "store": "true"
        },
        "feed_url": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "store": "true"
        },
        "created_ts": {
            "type": "date",
            "store": "true"
        },
        "hot_until": {"type": "date", "format": "date_hour_minute_second_fraction"},
        "description": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "mi_tv_id": {"type": "integer"},
        "total_views": {"type": "long"},
        "month_views": {"type": "long"},
        "week_views": {"type": "long"},
        "day_views": {"type": "long"},
        "blocked_countries": {"type": "keyword"},
        "linked_persons": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "id": {"type": "integer"},
                "name": {"type": "keyword"}
            }
        },
        "linked_tags": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "id": {"type": "integer"},
                "name": {"type": "keyword"}
            }
        },
        "linked_hashtags":{
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "id": {"type": "integer"},
                "name": {"type": "keyword"}
            }
        },
    }
}
```

My query:

```
GET /video_idx/_search
{
    "aggs": {
        "mi_tv_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "mi_tv_id",
                "size": 10
            }
        },
        "linked_hashtags_id": {
            "aggs": {
                "linked_hashtags_id": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "linked_hashtags.id",
                        "size": 10
                    }
                }
            },
            "nested": {
                "path": "linked_hashtags"
            }
        },
        "author_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "author_id",
                "size": 10
            }
        },
        "linked_tags_id": {
            "aggs": {
                "linked_tags_id": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "linked_tags.id",
                        "size": 10
                    }
                }
            },
            "nested": {
                "path": "linked_tags"
            }
        },
        "linked_persons_id": {
            "aggs": {
                "linked_persons_id": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "linked_persons.id",
                        "size": 10
                    }
                }
            },
            "nested": {
                "path": "linked_persons"
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "inverse_title": {
                "pre_tags": ["<b>"],
                "type": "plain",
                "post_tags": ["</b>"]
            },
            "title": {
                "pre_tags": ["<b>"],
                "type": "plain",
                "post_tags": ["</b>"]
            }
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 20,
    "_source": {
      "includes":[ "mi_tv_id", "author_id", "hot_until", "id", "linked_persons", "linked_hashtags", "linked_tags", "total_views", "thumbnail_url", "feed_name", "feed_url", "duration", "is_club", "is_classic", "product_id", "created_ts", "title", "inverse_title", "description"]
     },
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "script_score": {
                "script": "\n                    double total = _score;\n    \n                    if (doc['total_views'].size() > 0) {total = total * Math.log(10 + 0.000087 * doc['total_views'].value)}\n                    if (doc['month_views'].size() > 0) {total = total * Math.log(10 + 0.00025 * doc['month_views'].value)}\n                    if (doc['week_views'].size() > 0) {total = total * Math.log(10 + 0.00077 * doc['week_views'].value)}\n                    if (doc['day_views'].size() > 0) {total = total * Math.log(10 + 0.0025 * doc['day_views'].value)}\n                    if (doc['hot_until'].size() > 0) {total = 1.5 * total}\n    \n                    if (doc['mi_tv_id'].size() > 0) {total = total * 1.5}\n    \n                    return total   \n                    "
            },
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "minimum_should_match": "20%",
                    "should": [{
                        "multi_match": {
                            "fields": ["title.basic_ngram_analyzer", "inverse_title.basic_ngram_analyzer"],
                            "operator": "and",
                            "tie_breaker": 1.0,
                            "minimum_should_match": "65%",
                            "type": "cross_fields",
                            "boost": 5.5,
                            "query": "\u0434\u043e\u043c 2"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "fields": ["title.keyword", "inverse_title.keyword"],
                            "operator": "and",
                            "tie_breaker": 1.0,
                            "minimum_should_match": "100%",
                            "type": "cross_fields",
                            "boost": 12.5,
                            "query": "\u0434\u043e\u043c 2"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "fields": ["title.translit_analyzer", "inverse_title.translit_analyzer"],
                            "operator": "and",
                            "tie_breaker": 1.0,
                            "minimum_should_match": "65%",
                            "type": "cross_fields",
                            "boost": 3,
                            "query": "\u0434\u043e\u043c 2"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "fields": ["title.numeric_analyzer", "inverse_title.numeric_analyzer"],
                            "operator": "and",
                            "tie_breaker": 1.0,
                            "minimum_should_match": "100%",
                            "type": "cross_fields",
                            "boost": 6,
                            "query": "\u0434\u043e\u043c 2"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "fields": ["title.basic_ngram_analyzer_no_digit", "inverse_title.basic_ngram_analyzer_no_digit"],
                            "operator": "and",
                            "tie_breaker": 1.0,
                            "minimum_should_match": "65%",
                            "type": "cross_fields",
                            "boost": 5.5,
                            "query": "\u0434\u043e\u043c 2"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "fields": ["title.basic_edge_ngram_analyzer", "inverse_title.basic_edge_ngram_analyzer"],
                            "operator": "and",
                            "tie_breaker": 1.0,
                            "minimum_should_match": "65%",
                            "type": "cross_fields",
                            "boost": 5.5,
                            "query": "\u0434\u043e\u043c 2"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "fields": ["title.translit_double_metaphone_analyzer", "inverse_title.translit_double_metaphone_analyzer"],
                            "operator": "and",
                            "tie_breaker": 1.0,
                            "minimum_should_match": "65%",
                            "type": "cross_fields",
                            "boost": 1,
                            "query": "\u0434\u043e\u043c 2"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "fields": ["description"],
                            "operator": "and",
                            "tie_breaker": 1.0,
                            "minimum_should_match": "100%",
                            "type": "cross_fields",
                            "boost": 1.0,
                            "query": "\u0434\u043e\u043c 2"
                        }
                    }],
                    "must_not": [{
                        "terms": {
                            "blocked_countries": ["RU"]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the query you're sending and also a sample document that you expect to match?

Comment: Of course.  Add info to question body. Obviously I expect to get all fields from _source field

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `_source.includes` field from your query?

Comment: Yes, of course. And retried it right now - not helps

Comment: What fields are missing?

Comment: All store fields: feed_name, feed_url, duration, is_club, is_classic, product_id, created_ts. I tried remove "store": true from mapping - not works

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all the stored field to the [`stored_fields` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/search-request-stored-fields.html) in your query:

```
"_source": {
  "includes":[ "mi_tv_id", "author_id", "hot_until", "id", "linked_persons", "linked_hashtags", "linked_tags", "total_views", "thumbnail_url", "feed_name", "feed_url", "duration", "is_club", "is_classic", "product_id", "created_ts", "title", "inverse_title", "description"]
 },
 "stored_fields": ["feed_name", "feed_url", "duration", "is_club", ...],
```

Comment: Unfortunately it not works( Added "stored_fields" to query - there isn't any effect on my result

Comment: Can you provide a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) so I can reproduce what you're seeing?